# Sums of Nested Radicals

Tags: sequences-and-series, nested-radicals

Let $a_1=\sqrt{2}$, $a_2=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}$ and $a_n$ be defined as 
$$a_n=\underbrace{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+...+\sqrt{2}}}}_{n-times}$$
for any $n\geq1$. Now consider the following infinite sum:
$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}(a_n-2)$$ 
Does this sum converge? If so what would be its limit? It is easy to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n-2)=0$ but this does not ensure us convergence of the sum. In general I would like to address the following question.
Given a nested radical of the following form
$$a_n=\underbrace{\sqrt[k]{b+\sqrt[k]{b+...+\sqrt[k]{b}}}}_{n-times}$$ where $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and $b\in\mathbb{R^+}$ such that 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=L$$ What could we say about the convergence of the infinite sum below
$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}(a_n-L)$$
If it converges does it posses a closed form? Is there a general result on these series?

Comment: Curious about this as well! Did you find anything about it in the meantime? Could help to compute the sum numerically and see if the digits match an OEIS sequence

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x)=\sqrt{2+x}$. Then $a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$, $a_1=\sqrt2$. $f(2)=2$ and $f'(2)=1/4$. There exists $n_0$ such that
$$
n\ge n_0\implies |f'(a_n)|\le\frac12.
$$
Then, if $n>n_0$, by the mean value theorem we have
$$
|a_n-2|=|f(a_{n-1)}-f(2)|\le\frac12\,|a_{n-1}-2|.
$$
Iterating we get
$$
|a_n-2|\le2^{n_0-n}|a_{n_0}-2|.
$$
The series $\sum(a_n-2)$ is thus convergent.

The argument can be applied to any sequence defined by a recurrence $a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$ suche that $f(\ell)=\ell$, $a_n\to\ell$ and $|f'(\ell)|<1$.