# If $f_0(x)=\sqrt{x}$ and $f_n(x) = \sqrt{x+f_{n-1}(x)}$, show $\lim_{n \to \infty}{f_n{(20)}}=5$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, soft-question

So I came across this silly video ["When mathematicians get bored (ep1)"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ra0XeqUKqYQ) on bprp fast's YouTube channel, and it mentions the following recursive sequence:

> For all natural $n \geq 1$,
> \begin{align}f_0(x) &= \sqrt{x}, \\
> f_n(x) &= \sqrt{x+f_{n-1}(x)}
> \end{align}

In the video, it is claimed that $\lim_{n \to \infty}{f_n{(20)}}=5$, but I couldn't actually prove this when I tried to!

I don't know whether I'm forgetting something obvious or not, but can someone sketch a proof for me or at least point me in the direction of a method of proof?

Much appreciated!

Comment: First, you must proof the existence of the limit (Hint: increasing bounded sequence). Then, apply limit on both sides on the recursive relationship and solve for $L$.

Comment: It's wrong equation

Comment: The map $t \mapsto g(t) = \sqrt{x + t}$ is a continuous increasing function in $t$ from $[0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$. In general, if you generate a sequence by repeat iteration of this type of function, the sequence will convergence to the fixed point immediately above or below the seed value $x_0$ (above if $x_1 = g(x_0) > x_0$ and below if $x_1 < x_0$) or diverge to $+\infty$ if $x_1 > x_0 >$ last fixed point. The proof is essentially the same for all $g$. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4166029) for an example.

Comment: @achillehui Thank you! The example you linked to is very nice and I can see how this all works now! :)

Comment: I'm sure I have seen this before, it turn out it is one of the abstract duplicated question. see  [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/115501) which is essentially the same question,...

Answer (score 2):

Use monotone convergence to show that the sequence converges, and then use
$$P=\sqrt{20+\sqrt{20+\sqrt{20+\dots}}}$$
which implies
$$P=\sqrt{20+P}\implies P^2=20+P\implies P=5$$

Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

First, you can forget the $x$ and simply define:

$$u_0=\sqrt{20}$$
$$u_{n+1}=\sqrt{20+u_n}=f(u_n)$$

where $f(x)=\sqrt{20+x}$; and show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}u_n=5$.

Since $f$ is an increasing function, and since $$u_1 = \sqrt{20+\sqrt{20}}>u_0,$$
the sequence $(u_n)$ is increasing by induction.

Also, since $u_0<5$, by induction, you can prove that $u_n<5$ for any $n$.

Therefore the sequence converges, and can converge only to the fixed point of $f$, that is 5 since $\sqrt{20+5}=5$.

Voilà!